# Angular 4 firebase .currentUser.getToken()

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, jwt, angularfire2, angular4-forms

How to resolve this problem?

> firebase.User.prototype.getToken is deprecated.
>   Please use firebase.User.prototype.getIdToken instead.

Here's my code:

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(
     response => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()
           .then(
              (token: string) => this.token = token
           )
     }
  )
  .catch(
     error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Comment: try using `getIdToken()` instead of `getToken()`

Comment: sorry for the late reply... thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().
```

New Firebase version had a lot of changes. you can check on the official documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Hope it helps!